# How to assign item from list to variable

Tags: python, list, iteration, assign, items

I have the following output:

```
datos=['Venta Casas CARRETERA NACIONAL, Nuevo León', 'Publicado el 29 de Abr', 'ABEDUL DE LADERAS', '3 Recámaras', '4.5 Baños', '300m² de Construcción', '300m² de Terreno', '2 Plantas', ' 81-1255-3166', ' Preguntale al vendedor', 'http://zuhausebienesraices.nocnok.com/', "INFOSTATS_ADOAnuncios('5', '30559440');"]
```

And I would like to assign a different variable to each item if it is in the list otherwise it will be 0. For example:

```
recamara= the string from the list that has the word "Recámara"
bano= the string from the list that has the string "Baño"
```

and so on. And if the word "Baño" is not in the list then `bano= 0`

Comment: Please [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags) a programming language so the right people can find your question.

Comment: It's important to mention that the variable will not always have the same position in the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
recamara = [s for s in datos if "Recámara" in s]
bano = [s for s in datos if "Baño" in s]

if len(recamara)==0:
    recamara = 0
else:
    print(recamara[0]) #print the entire list if there will be more than 1 string

if len(bano)==0:
    bano = 0
else:
    print(bano[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Python you can use list comprehension to do this.

```
datos = ['Venta Casas CARRETERA NACIONAL, Nuevo León', 'Publicado el 29 de Abr', 'ABEDUL DE LADERAS', '3 Recámaras', '4.5 Baños', '300m² de Construcción', '300m² de Terreno', '2 Plantas', ' 81-1255-3166', ' Preguntale al vendedor', 'http://zuhausebienesraices.nocnok.com/', "INFOSTATS_ADOAnuncios('5', '30559440');"]

# list of strings which has "Casas" in it
casas_list = [string for string in datos if "Casas" in string]

print(casas_list)

print(len(casas_list))
```